# Error -- No presence information in SharePoint form Library WF

Tags: workflow, error

I have a [image: sharePoint form Library] created in Info Path 2013, with a workflow.
the form is running well with the WF but for some users is not.
Once they submit the form the WF ended: 
orkflow recorded these events.

Date Occurred    Event Type                        User ID  Description  Outcome
14/03/2018 12:45    Error   No presence information System Account
An error has occurred in AccessRequestFormWF.